# SQLException, No value for parameter 5

Tags: java, mysql

I'm using a UI that I've built to get input and MySQL to store the data locally. However, when I use the MySQL insert function, I'm encountering the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 5
```

I only have four input fields, and four columns in the table; however, my debugger says I have seven value parameters. Here is the Insert statement:

```
private static final String GLInsert = "INSERT INTO gl_maint(GL_MAINT_NUM, GL_MAINT_NAME, GL_TYPE, BAL_FORWARD)"
        + "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE "
        + "GL_MAINT_NAME = ?, GL_MAINT_TYPE = ?, BAL_FORWARD = ?";
```

And the preparedStatement method:

```
public void InsertGL(String ANstr, String ANAstr, String AIstr, double balfor) {
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnCheck, user, password);
        GL_List = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        st = conn.prepareStatement(GLInsert);
        st.setString(1, ANstr);
        st.setString(2, ANAstr);
        st.setString(3, AIstr);
        st.setDouble(4, balfor);
        st.executeUpdate();
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {

        Logger.getLogger(GLMaintAcct.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: you have 7 `?` in your query, you should provide 7 param.

Comment: `"I only have four input fields"` - Count them again...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is you have `7` parameters according to this query:

```
   "INSERT INTO gl_maint(GL_MAINT_NUM, GL_MAINT_NAME, GL_TYPE, BAL_FORWARD)"
    + "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE "
    + "GL_MAINT_NAME = ?, GL_MAINT_TYPE = ?, BAL_FORWARD = ?";
```

But you have just `4` value assigned like below:

```
     st.setString(1, ANstr);
     st.setString(2, ANAstr);
     st.setString(3, AIstr);
     st.setDouble(4, balfor);
```

You should add other `3` values like this providing their `types`:

```
     st.setString(5, value5);
     st.setDouble(6, value6);
     st.setString(7, value7);
```